# Using heat.colours in geom_tile

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a tile plot using a custom scale_file_gradientn palette, but the colours aren't quite right - and correcting it is a massive pain. The image shows the current version, though without axis labels (data not yet ready to be shared!).

[current version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwVo4.png)

Instead, I'd like to use the heat.colors palette. (I need the 0 value to be white, so viridis and similar palettes are not a good option here, I think).

However, I am struggling to find the right code for incorporating heat.colours into the ggplot2 geom_tile function. Can anyone advise?

Below is the code for my previous version using the custom palette, in case it is helpful.

```
ptile<-ggplot(dftabtile, aes(y=Var1, x=icd_ord, fill=Freq))

ptile<- ptile + geom_tile(color="Black", size=0.1) + coord_equal() + labs(y = "y values", x="x values" ) + theme_minimal() + xangle_theme

tile_red <- ptile  + scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("white", "#f2e8eb", "#e5d2d7","#d8bcc3", "#cba6af","#be909c", "#b17a88", "#a46474", "#974e60", "#8a384c","#7d2239"), values=c(0,0.0001,0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1), name="# Data points")

tile_red

ggsave("demo.png", width=400, height=200, units="mm")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it might help cause you didn't provide your data, but have you tried using `scale_fill_brewer` instead of `scale_fill_gradient` ?

```
library(tidyverse) 

library(RColorBrewer)

display.brewer.all()

ftabtile %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y=Var1,
             x=icd_ord,
             fill=Freq)) +
  geom_tile(color="Black", size=0.1)+
  coord_equal() + 
  labs(y = "y values", x="x values" ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  xangle_theme +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")
```

Comment: Hi - thanks very much for your reply and sorry for slow response but have had IT issues so only just able to look at this again. Unfortunately I can't provide the data for disclosure reasons. but if I try scale_fill_brewer I get the following error message, presumably because Freq is an integer variable?                                         "Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale"